# rails capistrano deploy is success but i don't access my deploy rails homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I try rails deploy in my local with capistrano3

I use commands:

```
cap production deploy:check
cap production deploy
```

when I using these commands I don't see any error

but I don't know how to access my deployed rails...

How can I find my rails homepage or next solution??

I want rails deploy in my local using unicon, nginx, capistrano3

/Capfile

```
require "capistrano/rails"
require "capistrano/passenger"
require "capistrano/rbenv"
require "capistrano/bundler"
require "capistrano/rails/assets"
```

/config/deploy/production.rb

```
set :stage, :production
set :rails_env, :production
set :branch, "master"

server '113.198.244.128', user: 'kh', roles: %w{app web db}
```

/config/deploy.rb

```
lock "~> 3.11.0"

set :application, "deu"
set :repo_url, "https://github.com/kimchijoa/local_deu.git"
set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true
set :puma_threads, [4, 16]
append :linked_files, 'config/master.key'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/deu"
```

/confg/database.yml

```
production:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    database: deu_ict_upload
    host: localhost
    pool: 5
    username: kh
    password: <edited out>
```

Comment: Hello, It's very insecure to post your passwords on internet, it's better for you to change it ASAP, even if it's not a production server

Comment: Did you configured your Nginx to serve from your deployed directory? Can you share your configuration?

Comment: My Nginx deployed directory is Maked up now

kh@DEU607:/var/www/deu$ ls
current  releases  repo  revisions.log  shared